# Loading images from a URL for a material texture with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift5, realitykit

I'm trying to create a custom material from a remote image to add to a ModelEntity with RealityKit. Works totally fine with a local image but trying anything remote I get a loading error.

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: RealityKit.TextureResource.(unknown context at $1b9817f08).LoadError.importFailureWithURL(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Demetrius_III_bust.png)

I've tried multiple images from different source, both http, https, .png, .jpg. Can't find a working example of this anywhere. If it matters the the id I'm passing to withName is a UUID.

```swift
func createMaterial(id: String, imageURL: String) -> Material{
        var material = SimpleMaterial()
        material.metallic = MaterialScalarParameter(floatLiteral: 0.0)
        material.roughness = MaterialScalarParameter(floatLiteral: 1.0)
        let texture: TextureResource = try! TextureResource.load(contentsOf: URL(string:imageURL)!, withName: id)

        let materialTexture: MaterialColorParameter = MaterialColorParameter.texture(texture)
        material.baseColor = materialTexture
        return material
 }
```

PS If anyone can recommend a good library to handle loading and caching images for this sort of use case that would be a huge help. Everything I've found seems targeted towards UIImages or SwiftUI Images.

Update 1: Here is the full error after wrapping the lines in a catch:

> [API] URL passed to REAssetManagerTextureNoNetworkSyncMemoryAssetCreateWithURL must be a file URL: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Demetrius_III_bust.png
>
> Failed to import entity from "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Demetrius_III_bust.png"

I also update my Info.plist's App Transport Security Settings to Allow Arbitrary Loads

Comment: As an experiment does the image load via a URLSession or UIImage API? Wondering if it’s an app level issue or an expectation of a local file for the TextureResource init. Also catch and print the error might shed some more light.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I updated the original question with a full error. I wonder if by "file URL" it means internal file? I've been using this library: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI to handle async image loading within my UI, I've been able to load remote images with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `contentsOf` parameter of `TextureResource.load()` requires an internal file URL not an external URL. I solved this in my case by manually downloading the images I needed first.

Comment: hello, i could not load data from my iphone. i get the url by using imagePicker delegate but i am always seeing "Failed to import resource from ...."

Comment: @elk_cloner I'm not sure how to help, you'd have to provide more detail. I'd suggest creating a new question and linking back to this one.